# Moving rows 'up and down' in a SQL database

Tags: sql

In the table I want to be able to 'move' rows. I have a column called `sortid`, which automatically on insert is one value higher than the highest value (easily found by selecting top value when sorting my sortid desc).

But I'm a bit confused on what query I'd use for the the 'up/down' actions for each row on my ASP.NET page. What query would I use to select the rows immediately 'below' or 'above' the row to be moved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moving a record up or down is done by swapping it with the record before or after, respectively.

If the `SortId` values are always continuous (i.e. you don't remove records which would cause a gap), then you can just add or subtract one to get the next or previous record. If the records are not guaranteed to be continuous, then you have to find the record next to the one that you want to move.

To find the `SortId` of the record before:

```
select max(SortId) from TheTable where SortId < @SortId
```

To find the `SortId` of the record after:

```
select min(SortId) from TheTable where SortId > @SortId
```

To swap the two records, you can use this trick that calculates one value from the other:

```
update TheTable
set SortId = @SortId1 + @SortId2 - SortId
where SortId in (@SortId1, @SortId2)
```

Comment: Nifty trick in one elegant update.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to increment all the `sortid` fields of the rows "below" just before `INSERT`ing the new row. You can do this with an `UPDATE` command immediately followed by an `INSERT` command. Let's say you're inserting a row at position 10. Then you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET sortid = sortid + 1 WHERE sortid >= 10;
INSERT INTO your_table (..., sortid) VALUES (..., 10);
```

You should probably wrap that up in a [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) to ensure that the operation is carried out [atomically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29).

As for the up/down actions, you wouldn't want to do an `INSERT`. The above is only appropriate for adding *new* rows at a particular "location". For the up/down action, you can simply "swap" the `sortid` value of the two rows, as [@Guffa suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101513/moving-rows-up-and-down-in-a-database-sql-query-help/4101595#4101595).

Answer (score 1):

For getting the rows above the target row.

```
select * from [TableName]
where sortid > (select sortid from [TableName]
                where id = @id)
```

For the ones below, just use `<` instead.