# Calc a Moving Average of Temps from a 24 hour (cyclic) column of entries?

Tags: sql

I am amazed this question doesn't seem to have been asked before, but if so, my pretty exhaustive searches have not discovered it.

I have a simple ring buffer of temperatures in a column from which I want calculate the average value.

The sql table looks like this (column names shown in top row) ...

```
uid Temp
1   70
2   70
3   70
4   70
5   70
6   69
7   69
8   69
9   69
10  69
```

Every time I obtain a new temperature, I want to shift the "Temp" column up one row before writing the newest value into slot '10' so I can get the average value of the column data.

There must be a simple way to do this, that I haven't figured out yet. :-(

Comment: What database are you using?  Why do you want to store all the records as a ring instead of in a big table (which seems more natural)?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101513/moving-rows-up-and-down-in-a-database-sql-query-help

Comment: If you want a decent answer, please tell us the name of the database, and explain why a simple file or a normal table application (@Gordon) is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the shift like this:

```
delete from buffer where id = 1;

update buffer set id = id - 1;

insert into buffer(id, temp) values(10, @temp);
```

However, I would keep all the temperature values and use another method to get the 10-unit moving average.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The temps are recorded every 10 minutes running from 00:00-24:00 hours and then circling back around to 00:00 to start a new day, but at the 00:00 mark the entire 'old' day is moved one column to the right (history column) and then the (left) 'new' column cleared in readiness for the new day's temperatures.  The new/old day temps are then charted for comparison. SO long story short. Rather than chase numbers around I thought it easier to just keep the last 10 readings in a stable cyclic array.  Does this change your "another method' thoughts?

Comment: Tried the suggested code but its a no-go.  I simplified the problem for this discussion.  There are actually many columns in the full Table.  The above method deletes the first row (and thus other needed data).  I cannot delete or insert rows.  I must just manipulate the 'Temp' column data ONLY.   [:-)}

Comment: In other words, I need to UPDATE all Temp's from uid= 1 to 9 where temp(n)=temp(n+1),  Then I will update temp(10) with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !!

```
-- shift column values up one row.
UPDATE [myTable] 
SET [temp] = (SELECT [temp]
                  FROM [myTable] AS s2
                  WHERE s2.[uid] = ([myTable].[uid] +1))
WHERE [uid] <= 9;
```

This moves just the specific cells up one row, as desired.

It was more complicated than I thought it would be, but this seems to work exactly as I needed.
  [:-)}